# How are electrons "captured" in magnetron sputtering deposition?

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics

To clarify,I am thinking about certain PVD coating technology called magnetron sputtering, vacuum chamber is filled with noble gas and glow discharge plasma sputters target whose atoms deposit as thin film on object.

There are various ways to do the PVD plasma coating,DC,AC from audio frequencies to RF,and then there is this magnetron sputtering I am writting about,it have permanent magnets arranged in such way to capture electrons.

My question is to anyone familiar with this thing,how can it capture electrons? Does it somehow work on the fact that electrons have higher mobily? How does it separate and trap these electrons?

Comment: The point is to try and keep electrons in the plasma, to enhance ionization of neutral gas atoms to increase the ion density and thus the sputter rate. Keeping most electrons from flying out of the plasma volume can be done with magnetic fields. I would not really say 'captured', but redirected or reflected  back.